# Listview like using foreach - MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a list of 20 items... after every 5 I want to add a div for column and every item will have their own divs and.. here is what am trying to produce using foreach/for but I am having problems deciding how I should be setting up my for/foreach loop to produce the following HTML

```
<div class="oc_column">
            <div class="oc_row">
                <div class="oc_left"><img src="/images/oc1.png" width="26" height="23" alt="" title=""></div>
                <div class="oc_right">Items 1</div>
            </div>
            <div class="oc_row">
                <div class="oc_left"><img src="/images/oc2.png" width="26" height="23" alt="" title=""></div>
                <div class="oc_right">Items 2</div>
            </div>
            <div class="oc_row">
                <div class="oc_left"><img src="/images/oc3.png" width="26" height="23" alt="" title=""></div>
                <div class="oc_right">Items 3</div>
            </div>
            <div class="oc_row">
                <div class="oc_left"><img src="/images/oc4.png" width="26" height="23" alt="" title=""></div>
                <div class="oc_right">Items 4</div>
            </div>
            <div class="oc_row">
                <div class="oc_left"><img src="/images/oc5.png" width="26" height="23" alt="" title=""></div>
                <div class="oc_right">Item 5</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="oc_column">
            <div class="oc_row">
                <div class="oc_left"><img src="/images/oc6.png" width="26" height="23" alt="" title=""></div>
                <div class="oc_right">Item 6</div>
            </div>
            <div class="oc_row">
                <div class="oc_left"><img src="/images/oc7.png" width="26" height="23" alt="" title=""></div>
                <div class="oc_right">Item 7</div>
            </div>
            <div class="oc_row">
                <div class="oc_left"><img src="/images/oc8.png" width="26" height="23" alt="" title=""></div>
                <div class="oc_right">Item 8</div>
            </div>
            <div class="oc_row">
                <div class="oc_left"><img src="/images/oc9.png" width="26" height="23" alt="" title=""></div>
                <div class="oc_right">Item 9</div>
            </div>
            <div class="oc_row">
                <div class="oc_left"><img src="/images/oc10.png" width="26" height="23" alt="" title=""></div>
                <div class="oc_right">Item 10</div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

UPDATE:
Here is the answer I was looking for, thank you for all the help

```
  @{
            int pageSize = 5;
            var totalPages = Model.Types.Count / pageSize;
            if (Model.Types.Count % pageSize != 0)
            {
                totalPages++;

            }
            for (int i = 0; i < totalPages; i++)
            {
                var types = Model.Types.Skip(i * pageSize).Take(pageSize);

                <div class="oc_column">
                    @foreach (var type in types)
                    {
                        <div class="oc_left"><img src="/images/oc1.png" width="26" height="23" alt="" title=""></div>
                        <div class="oc_right">@type.Description</div>

                    }
                </div>
            }
        }
```

Comment: and what is the question?

Comment: how do i break it up so that after every 5 items there is a div for column...

Comment: Get 5 at a time from the list and do stuff:                                         List = Div.Skip(0).Take(5);

Answer (score 1):

How about using a counter variable and check it's value and have the div you want.

```
@{ int counter=0; }
@foreach(var item in Model.Projects)
{    
  if(counter==0)
  {  
      @:<div class='column'>
  }
  counter++;
  <div class="oc_row">@item.Name</div>
  if (counter ==5)
  {
     @:</div>
     counter = 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: the column div is suppose to wrap the other divs, so every 5 there is a column div, what you have does not produce the desired results, just adds a div that doesnt do me any good

Comment: that would also work now thank you, i opted to have it done with take/skip

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a list of strings

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();

@for(int i=0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
   <div class="oc_column">

   for(; i < list.Count && i%5 != 0; i++)
   {
      <div class="oc_row">
        <div class="oc_left"><img src="/images/oc1.png" width="26" height="23" alt="" title=""></div>
        <div class="oc_right">Items 1</div>
      </div>
   }

   </div>
}
```

Comment: savme as shyju's answer, i need the column div to wrap the other 4

Answer (score 0):

`for` loop works fine, of course, but if you need a counter in a `foreach` just do:

```
@foreach (var item in list.Select((value, i) => new { i, value }))
{
    if (item.i == 0)
    {
        // do something with first item.value
    }
    else
    {
        // do something else with item.value
    }
}
```